# CakePHP and AngularJs in routing harmony: htaccess rules to send user to index.html or bootstrap index.php

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, angularjs

I'm building an app with CakePHP as my backend and AngularJS as my front-end framework.

I need to have CakePHP on the same server as my front-end code so it can serve the JSON I need.

Typically in CakePHP, one has the webroot folder, and besides the js/css/less/*, there is an index.php that hooks to CakePHP. Adding AngularJS, though, adds some complexity because I also want an index.html.

Here is the control flow I'd like to have:

- If the user goes to domain.com/, display index.html (but the route stays '*.com/'!)
- If the user goes to domain.com/#/home, display index.html and let Angular take care of the hash route
- If the user goes to domain.com/about (assuming the about page, html and all, is served by CakePHP), send them to index.php.
- If I make a AJAX call with domain.com/users/list.json, use index.php so that CakePHP can serve the JSON.

So my thought was I could have .htaccess rules take care of this. But I'm not quite sure what to write.

Right now I have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d #if it's not an existing directory
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f #if it's not an existing file
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L] #everything else, send to CakePHP
</IfModule>
```

Any ideas?

Would it be as simple as adding a line after the last condition like `RewriteRule / index.html [L]`?

Also, please feel free to suggest alternative setups with CakePHP and AngularJS.

Thanks!

---

**EDIT: I want to give more information on the build system I'm using for AngularJS and why it poses issues with just serving from the 'home.ctp' view.**

I'm using `ng-boilerplate` which uses `karma` for testing and `grunt` for concatenation, uglifying, and including scripts in index.html.

I think the build system is truly beautiful since it allows me to keep a modular structure.

Here is the directory structure for a typical `ng-boilerplate` front-end:

```
ng-boilerplate/
  |- build/                    # Development build
  |  | index.html
  |  | assets/
  |  | 
  |  |- angular/
  |- grunt-tasks/
  |- karma/
  |- src/                      # Actual source code I'm editing
  |  |- app/
  |  |  |- <app logic>
  |  |- assets/
  |  |  |- <static files>
  |  |- common/
  |  |  |- <reusable code>
  |  |- less/
  |  |  |- main.less
  |- vendor/
  |  |- angular-bootstrap/
  |  |- bootstrap/
  |  |- placeholders/
  |- build.config.js           # Build configuration specific to app
  |- Gruntfile.js
  |- module.prefix
  |- module.suffix
  |- package.json
```

(More info on each of these directories and folders here: https://github.com/joshdmiller/ng-boilerplate)

This makes for a difficult workflow, since I have to take the most recent 'build' (during development) and place the index.html file manually in `home.ctp` every time I edit index.html.

This is why my mind first went to .htaccess. Though, I understand that this idea has its own limitations if I ever do want to serve a page from CakePHP directly rather than bringing AngularJS into the picture.

Maybe I could configure the build system to place the index.html in the CakePHP's `home.ctp` view. Any ideas on this solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Keep it simple

One of Cake's main principles is [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) ("Keep it Simple (Stupid)").

You don't need any rewrite rule changes if the response for the url `/` is that of your index.html file

i.e. do the equivalent of this:

```
cd app
mv webroot/index.html View/Pages/home.ctp
<edit View/Pages/home.ctp>
```

If you put the following at the top of the view file:

```
<?php $this->layout = false; ?>
```

You can also leave the contents as the complete raw html file.

Doing this would remove the need for any `.htaccess` modifications.

A specific note about one of the bullet points:

> If the user goes to domain.com/#/home, display index.html and let Angular take care of the hash route

Nothing needs doing for that, as a url fragment is not sent by browsers with requests - the url received on the server is `domain.com/`.

### But if you really want to do it with mod rewrite only

Then all that's required is to add a rule for the url `/` - which is the only exception:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule  ^$ /index.html [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Be sure to use the `.htaccess` rules for the exact version of cake you're using as they changed over the years and can cause odd behavior using an older version of the rewrite rule with a newer version of Cake.

Note that the directory-exclusion condition isn't required and is probably not desired (it allows a directory listing with e.g. `/css`).

Comment: Thank you, AD7six! I've added more information in the original post about why I originally forwent the 'home.ctp' option. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

view link:

**Bake backend REST API**
I will reuse the database scheme of the CakePHP Blog tutorial.
Prepare posts table
Execute the following scripts to create a posts table in your MySQL database, it also initialized the sample data.

http://hantsy.blogspot.com.ar/2013/11/create-restful-application-with.html